# How to check whether at least one product is in-stock for a given attribute?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, product-attribute

I need to check whether at least one product is available (in-stock) for a given attribute. This is for the main navigation brand display. I need to hide brands which are currently have no in stock products associated to the particular brand. As I have hundred of brands if I load product collection for each and check, it crash the site due to the heavy load. So is there any other efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is build a product collection and filter by status and the attribute you need.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('brand_attribute', 'brand_value');
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
```

Then to get the amount of products you can call `$productCollection->getSize()`. This approach will work but is not so efficient as you will create a collection for each item in your navigation.

I would suggest the better way would be to update the collection that you use to build your navigation and join the product collection there so you have a size for each navigation item.